# twiki "Failed to load the perl module FindBin."

Tags: perl, twiki

I am trying to get TWIKI to work (virtual Server Hosteurope .. PLESK 11 CentOS 6).
When I run the configure script the following error appears:

```
   [root@lvpsx.x.x.x bin]# ./configure
Failed to load the perl module FindBin. The module was found at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm

Please ensure that:
   1 FindBin is installed,
   2 that the module is available on the @INC path,
   3 that the webserver user (root) has permission to read the FindBin.pm file.
The detailed error seen was:
Subroutine export_fail redefined at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 25.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 95.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 95.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 3) line 2.
```

I have only marginal knowledge about the usage of shells and much less experience with Perl.

I run the configure script as root. As Far as I know Apache runs as root too(PLESK 11).
`FindBin.pm` is located in the named dir and I already tried to set it to 777.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing VMS::Filespec, which seems to be the module FindBin is trying to require.

On the shell:

`cpanm VMS::Filespec`

If that doesn't work (the command fails), then try first:

`cpan App::cpanminus`

...and then try the first command again.

HTH

Francisco